# In what order do I have to rotate the extremties of the modron device?

Tags: planescape-torment

I have aquired an exoctic curiosity, a modron device, and after talking to a bunch of modrons realized that it is not just a game but a portal.

I have a few options of rotating and extending its extremities, yet: Which combination will trigger an effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination is:

- bend left knee
- extend left wing
- extend right wing
- rotate the right arm

It will open a portal to a new area and send you directly to it.